# Binding a Range Slider to Image Sequence

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, drawimage, rangeslider

I want to show a timelapse video but have it with a Range slider so the user can drag it back and forth.  I've tried with a video but I don't like the loading effect as you scroll.  I also exported the video as images and binded it to the range slider.  First question is, isn't there any plugins or applications out there that do this?  Maybe i'm searching the wrong terms.  Second is an image sequence the best way to do this?  In my code below I can get it to partially work, but I can't figure out how to resize the image, and it's way to big for the canvas.

```
<style>
  canvas {
    height: 650px;
    width: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="650px" width="1000px"></canvas>
<br>
<input id="my-input" type="range" min="1" max="50" value="1">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

    var totalImages = 50;
    var videoFrames = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalImages; i++) {
      var videoFrame = new Image;
      var videoFrameUrl = 'http://dacwebdesign.com/testing/images/timelapse-' + i + '.jpg';

      videoFrame.src = videoFrameUrl;
      videoFrames.push(videoFrame);
    }

  $("#my-input").on("input", function(event) {
    var currentImage = videoFrames[event.target.value - 1];
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(currentImage, 0, 0);
      });
</script>
```

Comment: If you know the size of your images, for example 1000/650, you can set the width and the height of the canvas in JS: `canvas.height = 650; canvas.width = 1000;`and then in CSS: `canvas{width:100%;}`. An other way: in JS you set `canvas.width = window.innerWidth` and then `canvas.height = canvas.width*.65`

Comment: Awesome thanks I’ll give it a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize the images to fit your canvas with:

```
var currentImage = videoFrames[event.target.value - 1];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var dstWidth = canvas.width;
var dstHeight = canvas.height;
var srcWidth = currentImage.naturalWidth;
var srcHeight = currentImage.naturalHeight;
context.drawImage(currentImage, 0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight, 0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
```

That does not take into account aspect ratios, so if your canvas has a different aspect ratio to your images, it will appear distorted.

Comment: I’ll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I just edited it to fix a typo. It was trying to get the size from the context, not the canvas.

Comment: Dude this worked perfectly.  Thank you so much!  I've been banging my head the last few days

Comment: Is there a way to preload the images.  The way this is set up the canvas is redrawn every spot on the range slider it has to load the image and every image is blurry.

Comment: If you have a high definition display (one where the pixels per inch is higher than the average monitor) it might look blurry because the canvas resolution is fixed to the 1000x650 resolution. You can address this by increasing the size of the canvas in the html tag while leaving the size in the css the same so it just increases the number of pixels, not the actual size. You could set the resolution in the html tag to twice what it is now to test this solution.

Comment: I would like to suggest an alternative to using the canvas. If you stacked all the images as normal img elements, you could move the one you want to see to the top using the css z index property. It might be simpler depending on what you want to do with this.